# Calculate and print difference between two date using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I need some help about an bash script.

This is the log on which i have to apply my script (3000 lines, it's a sample):

```
2019 nov 30 19:11:37 Job 1 started 
2019 nov 30 20:54:13 Job 1 finished
2019 nov 30 20:54:15 Job 2 started
2019 nov 30 22:12:04 Job 2 finished
2019 nov 30 22:12:06 Job 3 started 
2019 déc 01 00:59:30 Job 3 finished
2019 déc 01 00:59:32 Job 4 started 
2019 déc 01 00:59:58 Job 4 finished
```

We ask me to print the time elapse between the begin of Job X and the end of job X, like this:

```
Job 1 time elapsed : 600 seconds
Job 2 time elapsed : 788 seconds
.......
```

Somebody can help me ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: gawk has builtin date manipulation functions, and coreutils have an effective date manipulation tool (`date` obviously) which you can use in bash scripts.

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note that you can't reliably accomplish what you seek to do if those timestamps are in local time and if your local time zone observes DST. You'll get incorrect results around when around he switch from DST to standard time. You need to include the offset (e.g. `-0500`) in the time stamp to avoid that problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have done, but I leave you a simple shell script where you will surely be able to identify what you need.

```
#!/bin/bash

date1="2019 nov 30 19:11:37 Job 1 started"
date2="2019 nov 30 20:11:37 Job 1 started"

sec1=$(echo $date1 | cut -d" " -f4)
sec2=$(echo $date2 | cut -d" " -f4)

diff=$(expr $(date -d $sec2 +%s) - $(date -d $sec1 +%s))

echo Job 1 time elapsed : $diff seconds
```

Output:

```
Job 1 time elapsed : 3600 seconds
```

Comment: job 3 `expr $(date -d 00:59:30 +%s) - $(date -d 22:12:06 +%s)`, is already strange, a job running 3 days will be hard.

Comment: True! You just have to change date -d to acquire more information

Comment: Bash has built in integer arithmetic. You should basically never need `expr` unless you need to support legacy `sh `.

Comment: Also, [quote your variables.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Good tips! Thank you, Just out of curiosity, wouldn't it be better to use expr since it is more portable among different shells?